# How to delete specific files that are more than 90 days in a log directory

Tags: permissions, cron, permanent-delete

We are running our Application “JIRA” in Ubuntu version 16.4.6.

Ad we see that the logs folder in this application (Path : /opt/atlassian/jira/logs) is 22 GB and it's still growing and we see that most of the storage area filled by following access.logs

Example,  these logs look like this:

-rw-r----- 1 501 501 234202089 May  7 00:00 access_log.2020-05-06
-rw-r----- 1 501 501 212607616 May  8 00:00 access_log.2020-05-07
-rw-r----- 1 501 501 186463250 May  9 00:00 access_log.2020-05-08
-rw-r----- 1 501 501  52371707 May 10 00:00 access_log.2020-05-09
-rw-r----- 1 501 501  28145183 May 11 00:00 access_log.2020-05-10
-rw-r----- 1 501 501 202572869 May 12 00:00 access_log.2020-05-11
-rw-r----- 1 501 501 231068528 May 13 00:00 access_log.2020-05-12
-rw-r----- 1 501 501 233682968 May 14 00:00 access_log.2020-05-13
-rw-r----- 1 501 501 232376355 May 15 00:00 access_log.2020-05-14
-rw-r----- 1 501 501 192740162 May 16 00:00 access_log.2020-05-15

So we would like to delete the access logs that are more than 3 months and run a cron job for the same.

Could you please let me know if the following cron can do the job?

30 03 01 */3 * find /opt/atlassian/jira/logs/access_log* -mtime +90 -delete

I only want to delete access_log that are more than 90 days.

And I know executing the following will delete all the files that are more than 90 days in the logs directory which is not my objective.
30 03 01 */3 * find /opt/atlassian/jira/logs -mtime +90 -delete

Regards,
Aravind Viswanathan

Comment: Why don't you just try the command without the -delete parameter to check if it returns the files you expect?

Comment: This seems like something you would want to test yourself, rather than trusting to random internet folks.

Comment: Better post this question to a Jira forum. 1- to confirm it is safe to delete these files without affecting functionality. 2- Maybe Jira itself has a built-in log retention and archiving tools.

Comment: sounds like a job for `logrotate`

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple conditions to find arguments .

This is a simple version where i add a conditions on the name

```
find /opt/atlassian/jira/logs/ -name 'access_log*' -mtime +90 -delete
```